# How can I compare the STRIDE and DSSP output files of a particular pdb file?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, pdb

I have the pdb file of H-ras protein [5P21.pdb](http://rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=5P21). I am supposed to compare the output of [DSSP](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/dssp.html) and [STRIDE](http://webclu.bio.wzw.tum.de/cgi-bin/stride/stridecgi.py) files after feeding this pdb file to respective servers. My question is how to make a quick comparison between these two results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution that does not require you to upload the files to the servers: You can graphically visualize DSSP and Stride at the Sequence Page at RCSB PDB:

http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/remediatedSequence.do?structureId=5P21&bionumber=1

"add annotation" -> Stride and look at the graphical comparison between DSSP and Stride.